# registering a site with python request

Tags: python, request

```
import requests
import time

# 2Captcha API URL
api_url = "http://2captcha.com/in.php"

# Add your 2Captcha API key here
api_key = "API_KEY"

# Data required for CAPTCHA solving
sitekey = "6LfICGwdAAAAADhOg-AjpwXaOmwD7G9j-TiiT04p"
captcha_url = "https://cracked.io/member.php?action=register"
method = "userrecaptcha"
json = 1  # To receive the response in JSON format

# Sending a request to the 2Captcha API
response = requests.post(api_url, {
    'key': api_key,
    'method': method,
    'googlekey': sitekey,
    'pageurl': captcha_url,
    'json': json
})

# Checking the response from the API
if response.status_code == 200:
    result = response.json()
    if result["status"] == 1:
        captcha_id = result["request"]
        print(f"CAPTCHA sent successfully, captcha_id: {captcha_id}")

        # Sending a request to the 2Captcha API to wait for CAPTCHA solving
        captcha_result = None
        while captcha_result is None or captcha_result["status"] != 1:
            time.sleep(10)  # Check every 10 seconds
            captcha_response = requests.get(f"http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={api_key}&action=get&id={captcha_id}&json=1")
            captcha_result = captcha_response.json()
            if captcha_result["status"] == 1:
                print(f"CAPTCHA solved, result: {captcha_result['request']}")

                # Now, you can continue with the registration process
                username = "xifi362811"
                mail = "xifiwi3628@trazeco.com"
                password = "15231523"

                headers = {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Origin': 'https://cracked.io',
                    'Referer': 'https://cracked.io/member.php?action=register',
                    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
                    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"',
                    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
                    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
                }

                data = {
                  'username': username,
                  'email': mail,
                  'email2': mail,
                  'password': password,
                  'password2': password,
                  'accept_terms': '1',
                  'regsubmit': 'Submit Registration'
                }

                registration_response = requests.post('https://cracked.io/member.php?action=register', headers=headers, data=data)
                
                if "Successfully Registered" in registration_response.text:
                  print("Registration completed successfully.")
                else:
                      print("Registration failed. HTTP Response Content:")
                      print(response.status_code)

            else:
                print("CAPTCHA not solved, waiting...")
    else:
        print("There was an error while sending the CAPTCHA.")
else:
    print("There was an error while sending a request to the 2Captcha API.")
```

I wrote such code. A code trying to become a member of the craced.io site, but I couldn't do it anyway. I can't be a member of the site. Where did I go wrong? Is it on 2chapca?

I don't know much about python requests.

I don't understand where I got an error, the code is closing without any error, please help

I subscribed to cracked io site but it didn't work

Comment: What do you mean the code is closing ? try executing it from a terminal (like ` python myscript.py`) what you print should be visible and could help you